# Having a persistent issue with pip installs and google auth.credentials

Tags: bash, ubuntu, setuptools, gsutil

A while ago I was messing around with .bashrc and setuptools and I ran into this issue that I'm having trouble pip installing some (but weirdly not all) python packages.

For example, when running pip install cvxpy I get the following:
[image]

Running with sudo doesn't help, but when I run the pip install in a virtualenv everything is fine. I also tried to reinstall gsutil without succes...

I'm not really sure how to start fixing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Replace image by text.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to install just fine in a virtualenv, but not outside of one, it's pretty likely that the issue is coming from a difference in package sets or a package dependency conflict in your non-virtualenv environment. A good starting point would be checking out the differences between the versions of each package used in each environment (use `pip freeze` for this).

For *some* reason, imp is trying to load the google-cloud-logging package. Maybe try uninstalling that and see if you're able to install cvxpy?